# Dealing with inaccessible carcass under pier and beam house

Tags: crawlspace

We recently had 3 days of rain which were accompanied by a terrible odor. After confirming that it wasn't a sewage problem, I've determined that something took advantage of my recent siding work to crawl under my house and die.

I'm used to dragging dead things out from under my house, but not only can I not find this carcass, I think the rain spread it around underneath the house.

What kinds of things can I do to eliminate the odor of rotting animal? ...quick lime? ...something else?

The matter of water movement under the house is another issue...

Answer (score 1):

Quicklime is traditional, though a bit hazardous to handle. Time also does it. A hose end-sprayer with bleach or lysol **(don't mix the two, pick one)** might help at a lower hazard level and provide a way to apply the stuff where you cannot easily reach. The dead thing might also be in the walls rather than under the house.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like what I expected :-/ Quicklime will be difficult to apply, but bleach/lysol will require adding water under the house, which gets problematic. I think I may try the bleach first. Thanks!